# How do I use vue-code-highlight with Laravel 10

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-10

I'm trying to display code in my laravel 10 vue 3 project and I chose vue-code-highlight, though I'd be just as happy with vue-prism-component, vue-highlightjs or anything else that does the same thing.

My code is:

```
<script setup>
import { Head, Link, usePage, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import ContactForm from '@/Components/ContactForm.vue';
import BlogLayout from '@/Layouts/BlogLayout.vue';
import { component as VueCodeHighlight } from 'vue-code-highlight';

defineProps({
    posts: {
        type: Object,
    }
});

defineExpose({
    VueCodeHighlight
});

</script>

<template>
    <BlogLayout>
        <Head title="Home" />

        <div class="container-screen">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="post">
                    Post 1
                    <vue-code-highlight language="javascript">
                        <pre>
                            let x = 3;
                        </pre>
                    </vue-code-highlight>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BlogLayout>
</template>
```

I'm getting an error saying 'TypeError: g._self is undefined' which disappears if I comment out the `<vue-code-highlight>` block.

I've never seen '_self' notation before. How can I fix this?

Comment: Besides changing the library source code there's nothing you can specifically do to fix it. 
 I assume if the stacktrace was included it would show the error coming from within the `vue-code-highlight` component.  I see nothing on the library's github page indicating it's compatible with Vue 3, nor has it had any updates in 2 years.  You will need to find an alternative Vue 3 compatible library

Comment: I guess I just assume that anything vue supports vue3 these days, which I should have learnt isn't true. At least it isn't my code. Thanks for responding.